# Add orthogonality constraint to PDE over entire domain finite element

Tags: finite-element, pde, fenics

I have a nonlinear differential equation for $u:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ that I can express in the form:
$ \nabla (g(u)_{ij} \nabla(u)^j) = 0 $
 which is similar to the ["Nonlinear Poisson" example given in the Fenics tutorial](https://fenicsproject.org/docs/dolfin/1.6.0/python/demo/documented/nonlinear-poisson/python/documentation.html) except with the nonlinearity $g$ now a matrix.

However I would like to add an additional constraint of the form:

$u_x \cdot u_y = 0$.

I suspect there is a way to do this using Lagrange Multipliers, but I am not sure how to express this.

Comment: What do we mean here by ℝ2→ℝ3 transformation? Can this problem be analyzed in 2D? What is the domain? Can the g tensor be diagonalized for the whole domain?

Comment: Yes g can be diagonalized.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "analyzed in 2D" ... there isn't an obvious lower dimensional analog that comes to mind, though.

Comment: To provide some physical context, if that's helpful: $u$ is a map from a flat geometry to a surface in space with some constraints on how this happens. So you might think of a piece of paper becoming a cylinder, but of course the differential equation I listed gives some more interesting relations due to the nonlinearity $g(u)$.

Comment: If your nonlinear Poisson equation has the appropriate boundary conditions then it is already a well-posed problem. Maybe some form of nonlinearity in $g$ could lead to multiplicity of solutions; but in general there are no degrees of freedom here. Then how can we add here more constraints?

Comment: That, indeed, would have been my question as well: What makes you think that you can add an infinite-dimensional constraint to the problem? (Infinite-dimensional: It has to hold at all points of the domain.) In particular, even if you had a problem with only Neumann conditions, you would have *one* (finite-dimensional constraint) that you can impose...

Comment: I realize I may be asking an XY question, so to provide the full context I can refer you to this paper [Fitting surfaces with the Miura tessellation](https://hal-enpc.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01978795/document). Specifically see equations 10. The differential equation I provided in my original post is a form of (10a) while the constraint I would like to include is (10c).

Comment: I think that it would be a good idea to add the main points of the paper to your question.